# Changing Screen Width Makes Horizontal Scroll Bar Disappear

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables, scrollbar

Here's the example in jsfiddle [`here`](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/31217/).

Browsers tested:

Google Chrome: ok

Microsoft Edge (Problem):

[image]

[image]

Firefox (Problem):

[image]

Opera (Problem):

[image]

Any Solution ?

Comment: On the elements wit the offending scroll bars, can you just set 'overflow: none' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take it out of the Bootstrap responsive div. (`table-responsive`)

The Bootstrap responsive div wraps it in a scrolling element which conflicts quite badly with the resizing of the DataTable.

Problem solved, thank you.

Comment: Great! Good job. You should add a code example and later on mark your own answer as accepted. I fear a link to a fiddle in the question and "correct this"  as answer not help so much people in the future :)